# Ipython2 and ipython3 simultaneous work in my laptop

Tags: ipython

I have to run simultaneously ipython2 and ipython3 workbooks in my laptop. I have installed iPython2 but seems IPython3 not installed. I downloaded Ipython3 installation package but don't know how to install it to run.

Comment: Please specify what OS you're on, how was iPython2 installed, and what kind of package you downloaded.

Comment: I am running Windows 7. iPython2 was installed with Anaconda package.